# field separation in top command using awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a requirement to get a specific field from the output of `top`.  How do I do that?

I have

```
top -b -n 10 -d 10  

top - 05:16:04 up 24 days, 49 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 494 total,   1 running, 493 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65971500k total,  4028640k used, 61942860k free,   420512k buffers
Swap: 10485756k total,        0k used, 10485756k free,  1134108k cached
```

I require *time* from the `top` row, and the *used* value from the `Mem` row; in this example, that's `05:16:04` and `4028640k`.

The following awk script gets me the time field:

```
{
    for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {
        if($i~/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/){
           print $i
        }
    }
}
```

How do I extract the memory used?

Comment: awk'{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)
{if($i~/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/){print $i }}}'

Comment: Which is your expected output?

Comment: Hi Jose , i require 05:16:04 from first row and memory used 4028640k used from third row Mem: for all instances

Comment: Use `free` and `uptime` for that

Comment: it can also be achieved with one-line `grep` command(if you interested)

Answer (score 0):

Use the ability of awk to read "field" that are, by default separated by space, and fixed position of information (as field reference) of *top*

```
awk '$1 ~ /^top$/ { Time = $3 }
     $1 ~ /^Mem:$/ { Mem = $4 #it include the trailing "k"}
     END { print Time OFS Mem }
    '
```

I use the END section for printing and Variable to remind info for showing how to catch and use it later but a direct printf is enough in your case like this.

```
awk '/^top/{printf("%s",$3)}/^Mem:/{print OFS $4}'
```